# Show google maps marker in Swift 4

Tags: swift, google-maps-markers

I am want to call `drawMarker` function from outside the `geoCoder` but it doesn't work. If I call it from inside the `geoCoder` then marker shows on map but when I call it from outside the `geoCoder` or from another function the no marker shows even though the `mapView` is set in the geoCoder before the call!

```
private func setCamera(address: String) {
    let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
    geoCoder.geocodeAddressString(address) {
        (placemarks, error) in
        let placemark = placemarks?.first?.location?.coordinate
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: (placemark?.latitude)!, longitude: (placemark?.longitude)!, zoom: 10)
        self.mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
        self.view = self.mapView

        //self.drawMarker() This work
    }
    //self.drawMarker() This Does Not work
}

private func drawMarker() {
    self.mapView.clear()
    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 42.886447, longitude: -78.878369)
    marker.title = "Buffalo"
    marker.icon = UIImage(named: "ic_other")
    marker.map = self.mapView
}
```

Comment: can you please see the screenshot?

Comment: I would suggest implementing the map the way Google's iOS documentation recommends, by first adding a hidden map to the view controller with a default camera coordinate (mapView being a `lazy var` instance property), unhiding the map when `CLGeocoder` returns a coordinate and sets the camera, and then the third method that adds the marker to the map. You can add markers to the map from any scope (via delegates if the scope is wide enough) so you've made a mistake somewhere arranging your map.